# IntelliJ IDEA javadoc F1

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I want to create a good javadoc help for my code. The Android SDK showed in the second line **added in API level 3** (with link). How Can I do this or can't this be done with normal javadoc?

This is an example from the [original source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#3493):

```
public static final String ANDROID_ID
Added in API level 3
A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.
Note: When a device has multiple users (available on certain devices running Android 4.2 or higher), each user appears as a completely separate device, so the ANDROID_ID value is unique to each user.
Constant Value: "android_id"
```

But I can't see the **added** information. Do I need a special javadoc generator for it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer oracle's link for writing javadoc [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)
This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398583/3772041)
post is also pretty helpful

Comment: You must avoid posting link only answers, if you choose to do, you must post relevant parts of code, as links may die.

Comment: This is not helpful, because if you see the link (from my post), you can see, that the method hasn't special tags.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question. Can you please elaborate what you want to achieve? You are aware of `@link` and `@code` tags right?